# Twitter Widget not displaying in Joomla 2.5

Tags: javascript, joomla, twitter, joomla2.5

My Twitter widget does not display in Joomla 2.5. I deleted *script* from my (Super Users) blacklist in Joomla's Global Configurations, as well as I allowed JavaScript in the JCE Editor (Profiles Default Profile -> Editor Parameters -> Advanced). I'm not sure what else to try.

**Here are the Filter Tags for Super Users custom blacklist:**

> applet, body, bgsound, base, basefont, embed, frame, frameset, head,
>   html, id, ilayer, layer, link, meta, name, object, style, title, xml

**And here is the Twitter Widget:**

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"     
href="https://twitter.com/myname/favorites" data-widget
-id="myid">Favorite Tweets by @myname</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)

[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!

d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement

(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.

parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-

wjs");</script>
```

**EDIT**

This is all that is displayed:

> Favorite Tweets by @myname

Comment: When did you set up the widget? Was it recently or years ago?